# Firebase for Android SDK support?

Tags: android, firebase

What is the minimum Android SDK version to use Firebase on Android?

I see that the AndroidDrawing example works with API Level 17, but not 11. What exactly is the limit?

To be more precise: it doesn't crash, but the application never receives any data. So for the AndroidDrawing example I am basically drawing on my own.

edit: Platform version 4.0 (API Level 14) doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure it the API level is the reason why it fails? I the SDK a while back and it has always been Min. SDK API 8 (if I remember correctly that is). In fact, their current demos also have the same in their Manifests: [Android Chat](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) and [Android Drawing](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) (From: https://www.firebase.com/docs/examples.html). Have you considered some other factor other than the minimum SDK?

Comment: Any idea of what this "other factor" may be? I cloned the demo app from their repo, ran it on a Level 17 emulator and it worked, ran it on a Level 14 emulator and it didn't.

Comment: Actually, no. I don't. I was of course speculating considering the sample apps (and my earlier experience) suggests that minimum SDK level of 8 is used. They would have revised that parameter if it rendered apps non-functioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase dev here. If you grab the latest SDK build (v1.0.2, https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html), it should work all the way back to Android 2.2, which I believe is API Level 8. If after updating it still doesn't work, please enable logging

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

and either post the output or email it to support@firebase.com

Comment: 2.3.6 is API level 10, however, which is _not_ equivalent to level 8, of course. But good to know that it works back to level 10, anyway :) And the number of new features and functions between 8 and 10 is not that high.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 for firebase-analytics:17.2.0 minSdkVersion must be 16.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, I am surprised it hasn't moved up, but their quickstarts vs bill-of-materials 27.1.0 (current until just a couple days ago - 28.0.0 is out now) - they still reference minSdkVersion 16

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/59dce83ec6b5387a12ac8e083892ac54a5500f80/firestore/app/build.gradle#L11