# Does Google Firebase work on Android version 4.4.2(kitkat)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an app using the firebase database I have used in gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

But my app works well in android lollipop, marshmallow and nougat very well but doesn't work at all in android kitkat. Whenever I run app, it doesn't crash but it is not able to read or write data from firebase. Please help me in this case.

Comment: firebase works from API level 8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573044/firebase-for-android-sdk-support check this .

Comment: My app is working in many of the kitkat devices... But in some of the kitkat devices, in authentication, it remains loading, the database data keeps loading... Is this a problem of my app or the phone?

Comment: @ParthibDasGupta if you're having problems, post the [minimal code/steps necessary to reproduce those problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).

Comment: @FrankvanPufflen I don't have any problem with my code. The problem is my app works well in Android lollipop+ but faces problem in the authentication part of firebase in Android kitkat

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does

read the prerequisites in the following link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to solve it after couple of hours,

 The problem was with the **play services**,
Android Studio Was giving a warning that
**Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10298000 but found 9256032**
In short your phone has low version of play services installed than what it is needed.
To solve this you can use a lower version of play services in your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'
```

or you can also update the google play services from play store